# Hide the Excel Application before Showing Userform

Tags: excel, vba, visibility

I have got this code below to hide my workbook in Excel VBA, but it doesn't work as expected because it still shows the application as a window there.....

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Worksheets("Main Page").Activate
    'ActiveWindow("GESTAO DE EXPEDIENTES.XLSM").Visible = False
    Windows("GESTAO DE EXPEDIENTES.XLSM").Visible = False
    LoginDAFForm.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you working on MAC or windows?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Application's `Visible` property.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Application.Visible = False
    LoginDAFForm.Show

End Sub
```

I personally would recommend that you show the application upon the userform's termination event. If you agree, then add this code to your **userform's code module** as well:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

    Application.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you at all, but it doesn't work as well properly because,  it still showS the sheetS when a close any form. I want to share this application( only forms) whithout sheets, it means the sheets should not be visible or available for others, because is there where are the DATA BASE...

Comment: Hiding the sheets has zero to do with the question you asked, just to let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Application.Visible` property to hide application. The code you used hide only the window you mentioned. See the code below

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Visible = False

LoginDAFForm.Show

End Sub
```

It is highly recommend to set `Application.Visible` property to `True` when you close the  userform. Otherwise you will not be able to see any other excel file which are being open. You can use K.Dᴀᴠɪs code for this and I'm just pasting it here

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

Application.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please note: you don't need `Worksheets("Main Page").Activate` here. It serve no purpose and generally speaking is not good practice anyway

Comment: thank you at all, but it doesn't work as well properly because,  it still show the sheet when a close any form. I want to share this application whithout

Comment: Thank you @Zac I amended the answer to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: @arcenio I think you need to veryhide the sheets. That will hide sheets from regular users as veryhidden sheets can't un-hide without vba.