# excel open UserForm1 without excelfile opens

Tags: excel, vba

I asked the same question for a Word document and got an answer. Now it's my turn in Excel and unfortunately the same structure of the code does not work here. There are similar questions in the forum but without an answer unfortunately.

I only want to open my UserForm1 in Excel with VBA without the excel opens.

My code for "ThisWorkbook" looks like this: But I have the problem that in the background file is grayed see picture.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

In the forum the answer is Application.quit and similar which do not work, because then another open document closes, but I don't want that, I just want this document to be affected.

[image: UserForm1 with gray background excel]

Comment: have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58279885/hide-the-excel-application-before-showing-userform?

Comment: @FunThomas yes see that. But if i go with Application.visible = False, it makes all excel files not visible if i have open another excel before.

Comment: So you want to hide the current workbook and the "grey" application window (that is displayed if no workbook is visible), but if there is a different workbook open, you still want to display it?

Comment: Yes so for example i have anothwr excel open. And if i open my excel with vba it should open only the userform1 from it and the other excel (which was already open) should change nothing on him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following logic hides the workbook but continues to show other open Excel files. If no other Excel file is open, it uses `Application.Visible = False` to hide the Excel Application Window.

Put the following Sub and Function into a regular Module. In theory, you could put everything into the workbook.open-Trigger, but that makes it hard to test. I think it's good programming practice to keep trigger code as short as possible.

```
Sub showLoginForm()
    If isSheetVisible Then
        ' Only Hide this workbook and keep the other workbooks visible
        ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False
    Else
        ' There is no other workbook visible, hide Excel
        Application.Visible = False
    End If
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Function isSheetVisible() As Boolean
    ' Checks if any workbook except the current one is visible
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If Not wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
            Dim win As Window
            For Each win In wb.Windows
                If win.Visible Then isSheetVisible = True
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

In your Workbook code, you just put the call to the routine that displays the form

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    showLoginForm
End Sub
```

And in the code of the form, put the following code (adapt it to your program logic and your button names)

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = True
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

You should add the QueryClose-trigger to make Excel visible in all cases, even if the user closes the form using the red x-button.

Comment: Debuging: "object required" for LoginDAFForm.Show :(

Comment: Sorry, mixed up the name of the userform - this was the name of the form in the question I mentioned in the comment. Edited my answer.

Comment: if i close the UserForm with x on right corner it opens the excel file but want that it closes so added this code:

''Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    Dim appExcel As Object
    Set appExcel = Application
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    'ThisWorkbook.Close
    'appExcel.Quit
    ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Close
End Sub'''


but when i close the UserForm1 from the "x" right corner, it closes but a grey window is still here, like in the picture abow in my question

Comment: The grey window is the Excel application and is displayed when no workbook is there. If you don't want to see it and keep Excel hidden, it will stay "as a zombie" in memory. So the only way is to close Excel completely. Maybe use something like `If Not isSheetVisible Then Application.Quit`

Comment: Ah okay but application quit will quit all excel windows :( is there any code for the current application or like that

Comment: The function `isSheetVisible` should check if another workbook is visible. Execute `Quit` only if it returns False

Answer (score 0):

Hide the application, like so:

```
Sub ShowaForm()
    Application.Visible = False
    Userform1.Show
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I think OP want's to hide everything and display only the form.

Comment: Right, of course. Code adjusted accordingly!

Comment: It is a rather risky operation though, any error and the app remains invisible

Comment: Application.visible isnt a good option for me becouse it closes every excel file but i just want the file, whch i open

Comment: And i want that the UserForm opens with opening the file (at start) so i have to go also with Sub Workbook_Open()